# How can I clone a hasura project as a collaborator?

Tags: hasura

We are working on a node-express application and I have been assigned the collaborator role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hasura's Docs,

> The owner and collaborators should push changes to the upstream origin (like GitHub) and pull changes regularly to avoid conflicts arising later.

This means that Hasura doesn't do version control for your codebase and you should be just pulling it from a git repo where you and all other collaborators push code to.

Rest of the steps are fairly explained in official docs on [Collaborating on a Hasura Project](https://docs.hasura.io/0.15/manual/project/collaboration.html).